# Rails REST api setup: json arrays for multiple value columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord

I'm a little confused, and need some design help/input

I have a relational DB, and what I am doing is creating views/materialized views from my data that RoR will use activerecord to consume and output in json or xml, but I'm mainly concerned with JSON in this question

lets say i create a view from customer and phone tables

after creating that view, a select outputs the following rows

```
+-----+----+----------+----------+--------------+
|     | ID |   name   | Phone_id | Phone_number |
+-----+----+----------+----------+--------------+
|   1 | 77 | Jay Blow |      771 |   1234567889 |
|   2 | 77 | Jay Blow |      772 |   5674291988 |
+-----+----+----------+----------+--------------+
```

i place the new view in the activerecord, and i want the JSON to be represneted like this after calling the route /customer/77

```
{
    "id": "77",
    "name": "Jay Blow",
    "phone": [
        {
            "id": "771",
            "number": "1234567889"
        },
        {
            "id": "772",
            "number": "5674291988"
        }
    ]
}
```

am i off base here to want this to be the desired way to output the data? Or am i not considering something vital? like this isnt the way active record works?

Answer (score 0):

You can create response like {:id => 123, :name => 'name here', :phone => {:id => 23, :number => '' }}

Answer (score 0):

You want to write a custom renderer for your json. I suggest you to check [JBuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder), it's simple and effective: you write a file in `app/views/yourcontroller/index.jbuilder` and with some simple Ruby code you are able to generate whatever JSON output you want. In this specific case however, if your Customer has_many phones, you can do the following:

```
customer = Customer.find(customerid)
render json: customer.as_json(include: [:phones])
```